# Wrong string to double conversion in Qt QString

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting wrong conversion value from QString to double. Below is my code.

```
QString value = "0.525";
bool status = false;
double doubleVal = value.toDouble(&status);
```

The value I get for *doubleVal* is `0.52500000000000002`. and I was expecting it be `0.525`.

Can someone help me regarding this?
Thanks.

Comment: Base-10 decimals and base-2 floating point values cannot accurately represent the same (distinct) set of values. The floating point literal `0.525` translates to a floating point value that can only be accurately represented when using an infinite number of bits. See [IEEE 754 Converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) and observe the repeating digits in the mantissa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error reading float values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577561/error-reading-float-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: That's not a "wrong value". That's just a less-accurate-than-you-like approximation of the value. Floating-point numbers are not guaranteed to be exact, at least not for all values. But you can make it perfectly accurate in this case by comparing/printing in a way that accounts for the minor inaccuracy.

Answer (score 4):

Your expectation is rather unfounded if unfortunately all too common. You can only be sure that all non-integer real numbers have an infinite-length representation in a positional system in any base (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1874265/76513)).

A finite-length representation of a rational number exists only in *certain* bases. It happens that the rational number 525/1000 does not have finite-length representation in base 2; the representation in that base is 0.100001(1001). It has a finite-length representation in base 10 (among others).

The `double{0.525}` has only an infinite length representation in base 10. The  number `0.52500000000000002` is truncated to the number of decimal positions that cover the number of mantissa bits in IEEE-754 double precision binary representation.

Since a `float` or `double` is a positional representation in a base-2 system, you should expect that any non-integer real will need an infinite-length representation to be accurately represented, and only some will be able to be represented in a finite length.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [known issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47192). Or, rather, not an issue at all, which is why it's been closed without fixing.

This shouldn't be a problem: you should not rely on on a `double` having a specific value in all of its digits. Allow for a reasonable *epsilon* deviation / accuracy.